# Is it possible for Extjs 4.2 CSS vars to not be applied globally?

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, sass

I am using Extjs 4.2 and Sencha CMD 3.1 to customize the CSS of my application.

As instructed in [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming) by Sencha, I am setting the CSS vars in "/sass/vars" as follows

```
$grid-row-cell-font-size : 16px;
$grid-row-cell-focus-border-style : solid;
$grid-row-cell-line-height : 40px;
$tree-icon-spacing : 10px;
```

but all these changes are global -- they apply to the treepanel that I wanted to change but also in all other gridpanels and treepanels.

The attributes above are only available as CSS vars (they aren't in the Mixin for treepanel), so I don't know how to make it such that only the tree I want to customize is affected by the vars.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something or can't you just use the [cls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-cls) class of the TreePanel?

```
cls: 'your-custom-css-class'
```